# Unique Positive Definite Square Root of a Positive Definite Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, self-learning

If $A$ be an $n\times n$ positive definite matrix, then there exists a unique positive definite matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$.

My question is how to get this $B$. What is the name of the algorithm for finding $B$?

Comment: I would assume that positive definite in this context includes symmetry of the matrix $A$.

Answer (score 5):

The positive definite matrix $A$ is diagonalizable. Thus, it can be written in the form $A = V \cdot D\cdot V^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the **positive** eigenvalues on the main diagonal and $V$ contains $n$ linearly independent right hand eigenvectors as its columns. Actually, we can consider the matrix $V$ to be an orthogonal one (i.e. $V^{-1} = V^T$).

So: $$B=A^{1/2} = V\cdot D^{1/2}\cdot V^{-1} = V\cdot D^{1/2}\cdot  V^T$$

In that case, $B$ is a positive definite matrix. Indeed, consider any vector $x\neq \mathbf 0$. Then:
$$x^TBx=x^T VD^{1/2}V^Tx = (x^T V) \cdot D^{1/2} \cdot (x^TV)^T >0, $$ due to $D^{1/2}$ is a positive definite matrix.

---

Yes, this method uses [diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#By_diagonalization) of matrix $A$.

Comment: So this is called diagonalizable decomposition?

Comment: I think, you **have** to use an orthogonal $V$. Otherwise, I don't see why the resulting $B$ is positive definite.

Comment: @20824 Answer edited in order to be more clear.

Comment: @PhoemueX Why do you have to use the orthogonal one? Is there any counterexample?

Comment: @Andrei: Yes,  if we could use *any* invertible matrix, this would mean that every diagonalizable matrix with positive eigenvalues would be positive definite. I think if you consider something like $A = \left (\begin {matrix}1&-10000\\ 0&2\end {matrix}\right) $ this would give you a counterexample.

Comment: @PhoemueX Ah, yes. But if we restrict ourselves to symmetric matrices, then we can use any diagonalization since the square root is then unique right?

Comment: @AndreiKh: Good point, I think you are right. Nevertheless, without using the uniqueness, it seems hard to verify that $B D^{1/2} B^{-1}$ is indeed positive definite. Somehow, the symmetry of $A$ will force this to be true...